# Is it possible to skip Java plugins on a multi-mode project in sonarqube

Tags: java, ant, groovy, sonarqube

I'm using ant to run the build, and connected to sonarqube 4.3.
I've got a project that contains both groovy & a couple of PHP files.

When I run my sonarqube task, I get exceptions related to JaCoCo:

```
[sonar:sonar] 21:06:33.379 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 21:06:33.391 INFO  - Project coverage is set to 0% as no JaCoCo execution data has been dumped: /User/myhome/myproject/api/target/jacoco.exec
<snip>
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SquidIndex can't be null
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:145)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.DefaultJavaResourceLocator.getSquidIndex(DefaultJavaResourceLocator.java:57)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.DefaultJavaResourceLocator.findResourceByClassName(DefaultJavaResourceLocator.java:64)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.AbstractAnalyzer.getResource(AbstractAnalyzer.java:84)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.AbstractAnalyzer.readExecutionData(AbstractAnalyzer.java:147)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.AbstractAnalyzer.analyse(AbstractAnalyzer.java:107)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JaCoCoSensor.analyse(JaCoCoSensor.java:61)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:79)
```

If I understand right, it seems like its trying to get some Java code coverage data. But I don't actually have any Java code in here. The project is configured as a 'multi-language' project, but I would have expected sonar to be smart and only turn on plugins for languages that it  finds...Or does the fact that there is groovy code tripping things up?

Comment: Share `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in Java 2.2 version where the JaCoCoSensor executes even if the project does not contains Java Files, this should be fixed in Java 2.2.1 version (which should be released shortly).